# Find, trim and update a column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table containing Id and imgUrl. Previously, we have a specific url like "http://www.abc.com/images/folder1/12345.jpg" and 
"http://www.abc.com/images/folder2/12345.jpg". Now we want to remove the url part("http://www.abc.com/images/folder1/" and "http://www.abc.com/images/folder2/") in all column and wants to keep simply image name. We have a huge data of this.

What we want is, is there any sql script, so that it can loop the entire column, trim the url and only keep the image name and update the field?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET url = RIGHT(url, LOCATE('/', REVERSE(url)) - 1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba155/1

All credit goes to John Woo !

Answer (score 2):

MySQL [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function comes very handy in situations like this

```sql
UPDATE table1
   SET imgurl = SUBSTRING_INDEX(imgurl, '/', -1)
-- WHERE imgurl LIKE 'http://%'
```

Output:

```
| ID |    IMGURL |
|----|-----------|
|  1 | 12345.jpg |
|  2 | 12345.jpg |
```

*You may want to use `WHERE` to limit updates only to rows that haven't been updated yet*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5652c/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @JerryJones You're quite welcome :) If you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into REGEXP_REPLACE: https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

You can then simply just search using a regex pattern: `http://www.abc.com/images/folder[0-9]/`